# How to enable the Slick-Slider for a product grid on the Product description page (PDP page)?

Tags: magento2.3, slider, slick, pdp

I have a home page on which there are couple of slick enabled sliders working fine, although I'm trying to enable slick slider for a product grid on the pdp page, but it doesnt work. What i have done is add the classes of my product grid at the jquery section in grid.phtml. Can some one help me resolve this?
**the grid.phtml jquery code:**

```
jQuery(".block.related .block-content .products-grid .product-items").slick({
            dots: false,
            arrows: true,
             prevArrow:"<button type='button' class='slick-prev pull-left'><</button>",
            nextArrow:"<button type='button' class='slick-next pull-right'>></button>",
            infinite: true,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 4,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1280,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 3
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 768,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 600,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

**the product list template:**
[image: the product list template]

Comment: Check whether slick is loading or not on PDP and  is it initialized on element in which you have added class.

Comment: The slick is loading on the page but it is not initialised on my product class. I've also cross checked the classname heirarchy multiple times

Comment: Can you please update the question with the code you are trying, so one can get better idea about what is wrong there.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Is there any error in the console tab of browser?

Comment: Hello Rahul, Thanks for the help. It works fine now.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you let me know what was the issue?